# Android Studio - Enable native C++ debugging in existing older project (card.io Android Source)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am currently trying to understand how the native implementation of the [card.io Android Source](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source) does work. For this purpose, it would be great to have the possibility to debug the native `C++` code. Currently, my breakpoints are not respected.

I did try the following approaches:

1. Adjust the Application make file (Application.mk):

   ```
   APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
   APP_CFLAGS += -UNDEBUG -O0 -g -ggdb 
   APP_OPTIM := debug
   APP_CPPFLAGS += -DDMZ_DEBUG=1
   ```
2. Add buildtype to the build.gradle file of the SampleApp

   ```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
       }
       debug {
           debuggable true
       }
   }
   ```

**Note:**
I am using `Android Studio 3.1` with `Ubuntu 16.04` *(64-bit)* and if I create a new project with `C++` support, debugging is perfectly working.

We are debugging on an `Android 7.0` device; the project is using an `NDK-build` system.

Comment: The difference between current C++ NDK in Android Studio 3.X and the one used for the development of Card.io is the build/compilation tools which respectively are CMake and NDK-build. Android Studio and the Android Gradle Plugin have better integrations with CMake as they recommend it for any new project. So creating a new project and debugging it would mean ur using the newer integrations and not the one used for the development of card.io. To find the proper way of debugging card.io, one would need to create an new NDK-Build project and try it. https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/

Comment: But where is the integration defined? In a new project for example I can switch from CMake to NDK-build and debugging will still work. I just can't see then where the difference is in regard to the card.io project.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this link](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source/tree/master/card.io/src/main/jni) read **Compile** section..

> If everything is set up properly, the NDK build will be invoked by
>   gradle when card.io is built. But for debugging, you can use `./gradlew`
>   `buildNative` to kick off just this portion of the build.

If you face any errors in `./gradlew buildNative` then check [this thread](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source/issues/60).

I didn't check it, So Hope it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I'm getting the following error: Task 'buildNative' not found in project

Comment: Also if I run "./gradlew tasks" there is no buildNative listed

Comment: Make sure that you have installed the ndk and ndk-build is in your PATH. If not, set the environment variable for the ndk file

Comment: The ndk.dir is set in the local.properties of the project

Comment: [Read](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-an-android-command-line-application-using-the-ndk-build-tools) Set up your build environment section.

Comment: ./gradlew is actually working and I can also run assembleDebug, but not buildNative

Comment: buildNative is command inside NDK and to run it you need to set environment variable to indicate the location of the NDK directory.

Comment: Even though this answer got the bounty auto-assigned - the mentioned solution is not working.

Comment: If you're developing for multiple platforms and have more than one API version installed, make sure the environment is clean for the specific target build. Studio might be picking up incorrect paths.